# nearest neighbor algorithm copy element (city) to output array java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, csv, element

So I have a program written so far that reads in a csv file of cities and distances in the following format:

Alaska Mileage Chart,Anchorage,Anderson,Cantwell,
Anchorage,0,284,210,
Anderson,284,0,74,
Cantwell,210,74,0,

So the algorithm works and outputs the cities in the order they should be visited following the shortest path using the nearest neighbor algorithm always starting with Anchorage as the city of origin or starting city.

Using this data, the example output for the algorithm is: 1,3,2.  I have ran this with a 27 element chart and had good results as well.  I am using this small one for writing and debugging purposes.

Ideally the output I am looking for is the Name of the City and a cumulative milage.

Right now I am having working on trying to get the cities into an array that I can print out.  Help with both parts would be appreciated or help keeping in mind that is the end goal is appreciated as well.

My thought was that ultimately I may want to create an array of {string, int}

so my output would look something like this..

Anchorage       0

Cantwell        210

Anderson 284

I am able to set the first element of the array to 1, but can not get the 2nd and 3rd element of the new output array to correct

This is the code I am having a problem with:

```
public class TSPNearestNeighbor {

    private int numberOfNodes;
    private Stack<Integer> stack;

    public TSPNearestNeighbor()
    {
        stack = new Stack<>();
    }

     public void tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][])
    {

        numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[1].length;
//        System.out.print(numberOfNodes);


//        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(adjacencyMatrix));


        int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes];
 //       System.out.print(Arrays.toString(visited));

        visited[1] = 1;
 //       System.out.print(Arrays.toString(visited));

        stack.push(1);
        int element, dst = 0, i;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        boolean minFlag = false;
        System.out.print(1 + "\n");

        //System.arraycopy(arr_cities, 0, arr_final, 0, 1); // Copies Anchorage to Pos 1 always

        //System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(arr_final)+ "\n");

        while (!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            element = stack.peek();
            i = 1;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            while (i <= numberOfNodes-1)
            {
                if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0)
                {
                    if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i])
                    {
                        min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                        dst = i;
                        minFlag = true;

                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (minFlag)
            {
                visited[dst] = 1;
                stack.push(dst);
                System.out.print(dst + "\n");

                minFlag = false;
                continue;
            }
            stack.pop();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer your question slightly indirectly. You are making life hard for yourself by using arrays of objects. They make the code difficult to read and are hard to access. Things would become easier if you create a `City` class with appropriate methods to help you with the output.

For example:

```
class City {
    private final String name;
    private final Map<City,Integer> connections = new HashMap<>();

    public static addConnection(City from, City to, int distance) {
        from.connections.put(to, distance);
        to.connections.put(from, distance);
    }

    public int getDistanceTo(City other) {
        if (connections.containsKey(other))
            return connections.get(other);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non connection error");
    }
}
```

I've left out constructor, getters, setters for clarity.

Now outputting your path becomes quite a bit simpler:

```
public void outputPath(List<City> cities) {
    int cumulativeDistance = 0;
    City previous = null;
    for (City current: cities) {
        if (previous != null)
            cumulativeDistance += previous.getDistanceTo(current);
        System.out.println(current.getName + " " + cumulativeDistance);
        previous = current;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Ok that's helpful. I'll post a second answer with a solution to printing output using your current structures. However I recommend you get used to using classes to correctly represent structures early on. Arrays are rarely the correct approach in Java.

Comment: any updates on this question?   Thanks for your input so far.  I am still having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the existing structure you are using, you can output the cities in the path using:

```
public void printCities(Stack<Integer> path, int[][] distances, List<String> names) {
    int cumulativeDistance = 0;
    int previous = -1;
    for (int city: path) {
        if (previous != -1)
            cumulativeDistance += distances[previous][city];
        System.out.println(names.get(city) + " " + cumulativeDistance);
        previous = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `public void printCities(Stack<Integer> path, int[][] distances, ArrayList<String> names)`

Comment: I get how that works but what I do not get is how to insert that into what I already have.  Is that then included in the Class TSPNearestNeighbor  and I am going to request that output by temp.printCities(city) in the main;  or temp.printCities(names);